# Is there a way to make Pinterest recognize background images?

Tags: pinterest

Like adding a class of "data-pin-pin" instead of "data-pin-nopin" ? There are images within a slider but they are all background images so currently the pin button is not functioning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pinterest doesn't recognize background images.
If you cannot change them into non-background images maybe you can use a trick with putting the same set of images on the page but hide them using styles - Pinterest should see them anyway:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/path/to/my/image.jpg');">
<span style="display:none;"><img src="/path/to/my/image.jpg" /></span>
</div>
```